# Find specific answer

Tags: support, specific-answer

I'm almost positive that yesterday I was looking for a way to answer interactive questions inside a Dockerfile. I found how to do it using `echo`. While browsing through SO main site I saw a related answer where somebody used a string of an evil laugh e.g. "Muhahahahahahaha..." as an example of a string. Now I want to find that answer but even if I open everything from yesterday in my browser history I cannot locate it. Is there some better way than trying to search my local history, search using Google or ask here? The reason I want to locate that specific answer is that I want to follow-up my browsing history. This could be solved if SO kept a history for me which questions I did visit recently but I don't think they do.

Comment: SO doesn't keep a history of which pages you visited (unless you bookmarked it). Given that you only know a single string, did you try to google `site:stackoverflow.com Muhahahahahahaha`? It gives a few matches, but non seems to be docker related.

Comment: Did you try SO's own [advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)? You can search for answers only by writing "is:answer", for instance, and add other useful info you remember, also using wildcard characters. E. g. try something like "Muhaha* is:answer" or a version of it and see if it helps.

Comment: @BDL Thing is that the spelling wasn't the usual "Muhahahahahah" and that's one of the reasons I want to follow-up because I think that the spelling might have been "Mwuahahahahaha" which makes it more difficult to match in a search

Comment: If you use Chrome and login with a Google account, you can go to https://myactivity.google.com and search your browser history (there's a link in Chrome's History page (Ctrl+H) in the lower left).

Comment: Rereading my comment, I see some ambiguity. If you log into *Chrome* with a Google account, you can go to https://myactivity.google.com/... Nothing to do with how you log into Stack Overflow. My apologies if I confused anyone, or if I only confused myself :).